# How to show pop up in Xamarin forms. i should not use third party plugins

Tags: xamarin

How to show pop up in Xamarin Forms, without using third party plugins such as Rg plugin or x-labs plugin? 
See attached images.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5M3m.png)

Comment: Your perception of the urgency is not relevant here, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731

Comment: do you mean Xamarin iOS, Xamarin Android, Xamarin Forms, Xamarin Mac, etc?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 4):

There is an official guide on the Xamarin site to get simpel popups:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups/

I suggest reading it all, you can also make your own popups like rg.plugins by checking out their code and writing it yourself